# Foreground service is paused in Android 9 when USB is unplugged

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In service there is a receiver:

```
    IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    mFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
```

Service is a foreground service

```
 @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

          ...

        startForeground(NOT_ID, getNotification(type));
        return START_STICKY;
}
```

Service has notification running all time. When the service is "paused" notification is ok.

**Problem:**

When the USB charger is unplugged (The same thing happens connected to a PC or to a normal charger.) and the test is performed on Android 9 the receiver does not capture events, connection events, for example change Wi-Fi, connect by data or lose connection.

If I plug USB in, the events detectios works ok. To see the events I am using a test interface, not logcat.

I understand that this happens because I suppose in Android 9 the system pauses the services to save battery when the device is not plugged in.

Is there any way in Android 9 that the receiver is called when the USB is unpluged?

I tested in Android 8.1 and service is not paused.

Note: I can not declare the receiver in the manifest because from Android 6 it can not be done for battery reasons.

More info: To do the tests all the activities are completely closed and only the service and the notification is showing. If some activity is visible to user receiver works ok.